# Java 8: mapping list inisde a list

Tags: java, collections, set, java-stream

My `A1` class has these 2 attributes:

```
private String hour;
private List<A2> list;
```

`A2` class:

```
private String code;
private List<A3> list;
```

What I want to do is to find a prettier way with java 8 to write this:

```
Set<MyObject> set = new HashSet<MyObject>();
for (A1 pes : a1.getList()) {
    for (A2 pe : a2.getList()) {
       MyObject bppc = new MyObject (a2.getCode(), a1.getHour());
       set.add(bppc);
    }
}
```

Do you have any clue? 
Thanks.

Comment: I find the code to be readable enough without Java 8 features.

Comment: Are you sure you want a lot of equal objects? You do not use the variables you have defined inside your for-loops. Your class fields don't really match the code-snippet with the for-loops either.

Answer (score 1):

I find your version quite readable already, so I don't think I would rewrite it using streams. However, here is a solution using streams anyway:

```
a1.getList()
  .stream()
  .flatMap(pes -> 
         a2.getList()
           .stream()
           .map(pe -> new MyObject(a2.getCode(), a1.getHour())))
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```